# How can I update the Spring shell prompt without invoking a shell command?

Tags: spring-shell

I have an application using Spring shell version 2.1.11 (we are limited to Java 11) that provides commands to manage external services and a timer task to check the status of those services in the background.  When the status changes, either by a shell command or an external event changing the status of a service, the command prompt text should be updated to indicate the new status.  However, the text of the new prompt is not changed unless/until pressing the enter key or executing an application command in the terminal.

How do I update the text of the prompt after updating it from an external process?

I have tried using the LineReader class to printAbove the prompt, clear, redraw, and repaint the prompt.  While text prints above the prompt and the prompt is redrawn, the text of the prompt is not changed to reflect the new status.